# Transfer data from a Forms result sheet to another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, import

I have a simple form that inputs entries into a Sheets. All I want to do is open a new sheet and import the data from the forms sheet so I can manipulate it in my own way. I have tried:

```
=index('SHEETNAME'!A4:A4)
=SHEETNAME!A4
```

these formulas work but as soon as I get another entry on my Forms sheet the formula will skip that cell number.

**Example**

I get a new form input on A4 and to get the value of the new form data on my new sheet I use the formula:

```
=Form Responses!A4
```

All it does is change the formula to:

```
=Form Responses!A5
```

and leaves a blank block.

Comment: Check this [INDIRECT Function](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions05.html).

Answer (score 2):

A stab in the dark (but OP seems unlikely to revisit in the near future to provide clarification of the requirement):

```
=indirect("'Form Responses'!"&"A4")
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried [Pnuts' solution](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/65895/354) and it worked fine. I had tried the `=Arrayformula` but that did not work.

You can actually just put

```
=INDIRECT("Form Responses!A4")
```

Then when something posts it does not shove the rest of them down on the sheet you are importing data too.